# how to bind specific property in user control in itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls, itemscontrol

I have following UserControl :

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <CheckBox x:Name="seat" Margin="2,2,2,2.901" BorderBrush="#FF003FFF" Content="{Binding Path=TypeSSeat, ElementName=UserControl}"  />
</Grid>
```

With This CodeBehind :

```
    [DefaultValue(Nothing)]
public enum TypeSeat
{
   Nothing,FirstClass, businessclass , economyclass ,NoSeat
}
public partial class UCSeat : UserControl
{
    public TypeSeat TypeSSeat
    {

        get
        {
            return (TypeSeat)GetValue(ItemTextProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemTextProperty, value);
        }

    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTextProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("TypeSSeat", typeof(TypeSeat), typeof(UCSeat), new PropertyMetadata(default(TypeSeat)));
```

i want to fill itemscontrol  with this usercontrol but after run i have **just one checkBox**.

this is my windows code :

```
        <ItemsControl Name="icName" Height="366"  VerticalAlignment="Top"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=UCSeat}" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />

                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <local:UCSeat HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="156.8" TypeSSeat="{Binding seat1}" ToolTip="1"/>
                    <local:UCSeat HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="156.8" TypeSSeat="{Binding seat2}" ToolTip="2"/>
```

and with this code behind :

```
           List<SeatList> lst = new List<SeatList>();
         lst.Add(new SeatList { seat1 = TypeSeat.FirstClass, seat2 = TypeSeat.FirstClass, seat3 = TypeSeat.NoSeat, seat4 = TypeSeat.FirstClass, seat5 = TypeSeat.FirstClass, seat6 = TypeSeat.Nothing, seat7 = TypeSeat.Nothing, seat8 = TypeSeat.Nothing, seat9 = TypeSeat.Nothing, seat10 = TypeSeat.Nothing, seat11 = TypeSeat.Nothing, seat12 = TypeSeat.Nothing, seat13 = TypeSeat.Nothing, seat14 = TypeSeat.Nothing });
         icName.ItemsSource = lst;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataTemplate` uses a grid as it's layout control.  The two `UCSeat` user controls are placed in this grid without specifying which column they should be located in.

This means both `UCSeat` controls are placed on top of each other which might make it look as if only one checkbox is being displayed.

**Either** change the second `UCSeat` entry to include the `Grid.Column="1"` to make the second user control show in the second column

**OR** use a `StackPanel` container with `Orientation="Horizontal"` instead of the `Grid` container meaning both will layout horizontally automatically

Answer (score 2):

You have all the items there, however they are all stacked on top of each other.

To properly layout items you need to set your `ItemsPanelTemplate` to whatever container you are placing your items in (such as a `Grid`), and use the `ItemContainerStyle` to set any specific properties of your items (such as `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column`

Here's some sample XAML taken from [my blog post about the ItemsControl](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/)

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemContainerStyle -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Grid.Column"
                    Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
            <Setter Property="Grid.Row"
                    Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>

    <!-- ItemTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This assumes you are binding to a collection of objects that look something like this :

```
public class MyObjectModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ColumnIndex{ get; set; }
    public int RowIndex{ get; set; }
}
```

And results in something like this :

[image]

I'd highly recommend reading the actual [post](https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/09/17/wpf-itemscontrol-example/) as well if you're new to using an `ItemsControl` :)